# Php dynamic user profile url

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database with user information such as below:

```
 ID  Name         Pretty_name
 1   Steve_223    steve
 2   Ryan_03      ryan
```

Then, I have an `user_profile.php` that fetches relevant user information by accessing the database.

Now the question that I have is the following:

If a user goes to `example.com/user/steve`, I want to show the profile page of that person. Since the url is dynamic, how do I go about accessing the page for that user profile page? (Or how do I access the php file when the url is dynamic?)

*I am not that familiar with php. I read through some other questions on the site, but I thought I would ask a question to make things simpler to understand:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using Apache web server, what about using module *mod_rewrite* to call your user_profile.php script:

Add this line to the *VirtualHost* block of your Apache configuration file:

```
RewriteRule '^/user/(.*)$' '/user_profile.php?user=$1'
```

Thus, when a user type "http://example.com/user/steve" in his browser, he will get the page "http://example.com/user_profile.php?user=steve".

Eventually, in your user_profile.php script, the requested user name will be accessible in the variable `$_GET['user']`.

Comment: U can even add above mentipned rewrite rule in .htaccess file